# QImage into QML

Tags: qt, jpeg, qml, qimage

My application receives a live-stream of JPEGs over network (16 frames per second). The live-stream should be displayed using QML. The receiving part is written in C++, all the UI is written using QML.

How do I get the image data into the QML window? I have looked around how to get a QImage displayed, but I did not find a solution yet.

Implementing QDeclarativeImageProvider and refreshing the source of the image over and over again using a different name seems to be the only solution, see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativeimageprovider.html.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately the `Image` element is missing an `update()` method (to forcibly reset it). *Setting the very same source URL will not trigger an update*.

You can use something like this as a workaround:

```
Image {
    source: "image://yourImageProvider/something"
    cache: false
    function reload() {
        var oldSource = source;
        source = "";
        source = oldSource;
    }
}
```

(Or just switch between two URLS, with the same provider name, but different paths...)

You should also **push** those JPEGs you receive to the QML layer. Once you receive a new image, you should *emit a signal from C++'s side from some object exposed to the QML engine*, and connect that signal to that `reload()` function. The `Connections` element will help you there.

```
Connections {
    target: myC++ObjectExposedToTheQMLEngine
    onNewFrameReceived: image.reload(); 
}
```