# Qt/QML : Send QImage From C++ to QML and Display The QImage On GUI

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I created a class `Publisher` which periodically emits a `QImage` object.

However I'm having a tough time drawing the `QImage` to a QML element. It appears that the `Image` and `Canvas` QML components require a `QUrl` instead of a `QImage`, but I'm not sure how to convert my `QImage` to a `QUrl`. Edit4: When I say QUrl, I don't mean I'm trying to convert an image to a URL. That's nonsense. I mean I want to generate a reference to this image, which is not on disk, and the data type that QML components are asking for is a URL.

I've done some research and found that `QQuickImageProvider` provides a solution, but I haven't found any documentation explaining how to convert my `QImage` signal to a `QUrl` that I can use for drawing. Any example code or reference documentation would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help!

Edit1:

I've taken a look here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qquickimageprovider.html and I do not see how I pass a QImage to the quick image provider and from it create a QUrl.

Edit2. Here is the header. The implementation should not be important.

```
class Publisher
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Publisher(QObject* parent = 0);

    virtual ~Publisher(void);

Q_SIGNALS:

    void newImage(const QImage& newImage);
};
```

Edit 3. Here is my QML code, but I don't know how to draw my QImage, so this code is kind of meaningless.

**my main.cpp file**:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Publisher>("Components", 1, 0, "Publisher");

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/QQuickViewExample/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**my main.qml file**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Components 1.0

Rectangle {
    id : testRect
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Image{
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: myImage

        Publisher {
            id: myPub

            onNewImage: {
                myImage.source = newImage;  #I know this doesnt work, it needs a QUrl and not a QImage
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong about the image provider again?

Comment: I cannot find any example code that explains how to give the image provider my signal with a QImage.

Comment: What do you mean by "give your signal"? What signal would you like to emit, and how would you like it to be handled?

Comment: My custom class has been exported to QML and it emits a QImage signal periodically. I want the QImage signal to update the source of an Image component and thus have it drawn on the GUI.

Comment: What does it mean "it emits a QImage periodically"?

Comment: By periodically, I mean that every x seconds, my custom class reads an image from disk, stores the image data in a QImage, and calls "emit newImage(myImage)", where newImage is the signal name, and myImage is a QImage object.

Comment: What is the Publisher element supposed to do? You need to paste more code and context. This conversation feels like the "Twenty Questions".

Comment: I don't understand why more information about Publisher is necessary. All there is to know is that there is an exported C++ class that will emit a signal of type QImage. I don't understand how to now draw this QImage to a GUI.

Comment: Look, it is very hard for me to understand what you are trying to achieve. If you do not wish to clarify, it will be more difficult to find a good solution for your problem. Let us hope it is just me...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43546/discussion-between-trianta2-and-laszlo-papp)

Comment: Now, you would need to paste the QML experiment as well so that we can see what you have tried to achieve, or at least, you could post some pseudo-code that you would like to reach.

Comment: Please view my edits.

Comment: Thanks; now it is much clearer. Since you load the QImage based on your comment, why not emit with the path itself as opposed to the QImage? "newImageUrl/Path"? Why not add a new signal? You will need that because QImage has no url information for you. The responsibility of the class is only storing the image data, not the source where it came from, etc.

Comment: This is only for test purposes. I did not want to explain the complexity behind this test, but in reality, Publisher is connected to a websocket and it is receiving a stream of image data, formatting the image data in a QImage object, and then emitting the QImage object to the GUI to (hopefully) be drawn. There is no file I/O and I want to avoid file I/O.

Comment: Right, the work around is always there to save it into a path, although that could be overly slow with big QImages. I do not know the answer for this question, I am afraid, but at least the problem is now clear. :-)

Comment: As per IRC discussion with @peppe, you could probably make a dirty workaround by reimplementing requestImage, and the url from qml would be arbitrary since it would not be used in the C++ code.

Comment: Image provider should work, though achieving animation needed some trickery in Qt4 to force QML to update image with new contents. Don't remember details and can't check right now, just writing this to say it does work and google does find something relevant.

Comment: check https://www.huber.xyz/?p=477

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In other words, you have a class emitting a signal carrying a QImage and want to update an item in QML with that image? There are various solutions, none of which involves "converting a QImage to a QUrl" (whatever that means, surely you don't need to get a `data` URL carrying your image data...)

#### Use an image provider

This means you can use a plain `Image` item in your QML files.

1. Create a `QQuickImageProvider` subclass; give it a `QImage` member (the image to provider), override `requestImage` to provide that image (the actual `id` requested does not really matter, see below), and a slot that receives a `QImage` and updates the member.
2. Connect your `Publisher` signal to your provider's slot
3. Install the provider into the QML engine via `QQmlEngine::addImageProvider` (see `QQuickView::engine`); again the `id` does not really matter, just use a sensible one
4. In QML, just use a plain `Image` element with a source like this

   ```
   Image {
       id: myImage
       source: "image://providerIdPassedToAddImageProvider/foobar"
   }
   ```

   `foobar` will be passed to your provider, but again, it doesn't really matter.
5. We're almost there, we now only need a way to **push** the image updates to the QML world (otherwise Image will never know when to update itself). See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728337/qimage-into-qml/17734973#17734973) for how to do that with a `Connections` element and a bit of JS.

   Note that in general you don't need to make `Publisher` a QML type, you just need to create *one* instance in C++ and expose it to the QML world via `QQmlContext::setContextProperty`.

#### Use a custom Qt Quick 2 Item

`QQuickPaintedItem` is probably the most convenient for the job as it offers a `paint` method taking a `QPainter`. Hence the big plan is

1. Subclass `QQuickPaintedItem`: the subclass stores the `QImage` to be painted and has a slot that sets the new QImage. Also its `paint` implementation simply paints the image using `QPainter::drawImage`.
2. Expose the subclass to the QML world via `qmlRegisterType` (so that you can use it in QML)
3. Figure out a way to connect the signal carrying the new image to the items' slot.

   This might be the tricky part.

   To perform the connection in C++ you need a way to figure out that the item has been created (and get a pointer to it); usually one does this by means of assigning the `objectName` property to some value, then using `findChild` on the root object (as returned by `QQuickView::rootObject()`) to get a pointer to the item itself. Then you can use `connect` as usual.

   *Or*, could instead perform the connection in QML, just like above, via a `Connections` element on the publisher C++ object exposed to the QML world:

   ```
   MyItem {
       id: myItem
   }        

   Connections {
       target: thePublisherObjectExposedFromC++
       onNewImage: myItem.setImage(image)
   }
   ```

   This has the advantage of working no matter when you create the MyItem instance; but I'm not 100% sure it will work because I'm not sure you can handle the `QImage` type in QML.

Comment: For the record, I've just used the second technique suggested above in Qt5.4 successfully: to wire one C++ QtQuick item's QImage property to another C++ class which is QQuickPainter subclass and exists for the sole purpose of displaying QImage's.  I don't even need the connections, in the QML MyItem {image: otherItem.image;} binding works fine when otherItem emits an imageChanged.

Comment: Method 1 doesn't seem to work, because `QQuickImageProvider` is not a `QObject`, and therefore cannot have any slots. Using multiple inheritance to give it slots anyway seems to be a bad idea as well; MOC doesn't like it.

Answer (score 5):

When I've had image-producing C++ classes I've wanted to embed in QML, I've always done it by making the C++ class a subclass of `QDeclarativeItem` (there'll be a new QtQuick 2.0 equivalent of course), overriding the paint method with the appropriate drawing code, which maybe as simple as

```
void MyItem::paint(QPainter* painter,const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem*,QWidget*) {
  painter->drawImage(QPointF(0.0f,0.0f),_image);
}
```

if you have a QImage of the right size already... and Job Done.  For animation, just ping update() when there's something new to draw.

Comment: Note that OP seems to be asking about Qt Quick 2, your solution is QtQuick 1 based. The closest fit is `QQuickPaintedItem`.

Comment: `QQuickPaintedItem` is related to old painting method. For new technology and most performance, you need to use `QQuickItem` and use texture.

Answer (score 3):

```
QString getImage()
{
QByteArray byteArray;
QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
img.save(&buffer,"JPEG");
 //save image data in string
QString image("data:image/jpg;base64,");
image.append(QString::fromLatin1(byteArray.toBase64().data()));
return image;
}
```

send image string directly to qml source

Comment: This will probably work, but is knowlngly wasting resources.  Therefor I must downvote; the planet has too much CO2 already.

Comment: I, independently came up with the same solution, but, I used PNG instead of JPEG because it was lossless.

Answer (score 0):

Use QQuickItem.  There is a Qt example that does this.

C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.14.1\quick\scenegraph\threadedanimation

You make a class derived from QQuickItem and register it with qmlRegisterType.
Provide the override function 'updatePaintNode' in your class.  In the example, the class is 'Spinner'

In updatePaintNode:

Create a node class derived from QObject and QSGTransformNode

In the node class constructor:

Convert your Qimage to an QSGTexture with createTextureFromImage.

Create QSGSimpleTextureNode, set QSGTexture using setTexture

appendChildNode with QSGSimpleTextureNode

In QML add

```
import Spinner 1.0
```

and

```
Spinner {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 80
    spinning: true
}
```