# Pass QImage to QML

Tags: qt, qml, qimage

I am trying to pass a QImage to QML. Could someone help me? The code is below.

The problem is that all my attempts to make the image available for the image provider fail. I have tried using a Q_PROPERTY and a QImage member inside the class, but my provider always returns a null image when I try to access it to return.

How can I make the QImage available for the provider?

QML

```
Camera {
    id: camera

    captureMode: Camera.CaptureStillImage

    imageCapture {
        onImageCaptured: {
            manipulaImagem.imagem = preview;

            previewImage.source = manipulaImagem.recortarFotoPerfil(preview, viewfinder.mapRectToSource(Qt.rect(viewfinder.x, viewfinder.y, viewfinder.width, viewfinder.height)));
        }
    }
}
Image {
    id: previewImage

    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    anchors.top: parent.top

    width: parent.width
    height: parent.width
}
```

CPP

```
QImage manipulaImagem::recortarFotoPerfil(const QString &imagem, QRect rectRecorte)
{
    QUrl caminhoImagem(imagem);
    QQmlEngine *engine = QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this)->engine();
    QQmlImageProviderBase *imageProviderBase = engine->imageProvider(caminhoImagem.host());
    QQuickImageProvider *imageProvider = static_cast<QQuickImageProvider*>(imageProviderBase);

    QSize imageSize;
    QString imageId = caminhoImagem.path().remove(0, 1);
    QImage imagem1 = imageProvider->requestImage(imageId, &imageSize, imageSize);
    imagem1 = imageProvider->requestImage(imageId, &imageSize, imageSize);
    return imagem1;
}
```

When I use this I receive the following message:
Error: Cannot assign QImage to QUrl

I did not find anything to help me to solve this. How can I do that?

---

I have tried a different approach using the image provider as suggested by the links, but it still not working

Here is the code

.h

```
#ifndef MANIPULAIMAGEM_H
#define MANIPULAIMAGEM_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QImage>
#include <QQuickImageProvider>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

class manipulaImagem : public QObject, public QQuickImageProvider
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    QString recortarFotoPerfil(const QString &imagem, QRect rectRecorte);

public:
    manipulaImagem(QObject *parent = 0);

    QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize);

private:
    void alocaImagem(const QString &imagem, QRect rectRecorte);

    QImage imagemEditada;
};

#endif // MANIPULAIMAGEM_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "manipulaimagem.h"

#include <QDebug>

manipulaImagem::manipulaImagem(QObject *parent) : QQuickImageProvider(QQmlImageProviderBase::Image)
{

}

QImage manipulaImagem::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
{
    if(imagemEditada.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << "Request image: (image is null)";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Request image: image is OK";
    }

    return imagemEditada;
}

void manipulaImagem::alocaImagem(const QString &imagem, QRect rectRecorte)
{
    QUrl caminhoImagem(imagem);
    QQmlEngine *engine = QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this)->engine();
    QQmlImageProviderBase *imageProviderBase = engine->imageProvider(caminhoImagem.host());
    QQuickImageProvider *imageProvider = static_cast<QQuickImageProvider*>(imageProviderBase);

    QSize imageSize;
    QString imageId = caminhoImagem.path().remove(0, 1);
imagemEditada = imageProvider->requestImage(imageId, &imageSize, imageSize);

    if(imagemEditada.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << "Loading image failed";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Loading image OK";
    }
}

QString manipulaImagem::recortarFotoPerfil(const QString &imagem, QRect rectRecorte)
{
    this->alocaImagem(imagem, rectRecorte);

    QString a = "image://ProvedorImagens/imagemEditada";

    if(imagemEditada.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << "Imagem is null";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Imagem is loaded";
    }

    return a;
}
```

.qml

```
ManipulaImagem {
    id: manipulaImagem
}

Camera {
            id: camera

            captureMode: Camera.CaptureStillImage

            imageCapture {
                onImageCaptured: {
                    previewImage.source = manipulaImagem.recortarFotoPerfil(preview, viewfinder.mapRectToSource(Qt.rect(viewfinder.x, viewfinder.y, viewfinder.width, viewfinder.height)));
                }
            }
        }

Rectangle {
    id: previewRectangle

    visible: false

    anchors.fill: parent

    Image {
        id: previewImage

        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

        anchors.top: parent.top

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.width
    }
```

The output of this code is:

- Loading image OK
- Imagem is loaded
- Request image: (image is null)

QML Image: Failed to get image from provider: image://provedorimagens/imagemEditada

What happens is that when I call the functions the image is not null, but when I try to return the QImage using the provider it cant return the image. I dont know why but for the image provider the image is null.

How could I solve that?

Comment: You have to implement your own image provider in order to use `QImage` in QML. I have an example set up in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429371/qml-and-c-image-interoperability/27429586#27429586 just modify it for `QImage` instead of `QPixmap`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt/QML : Send QImage From C++ to QML and Display The QImage On GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691414/qt-qml-send-qimage-from-c-to-qml-and-display-the-qimage-on-gui)

Comment: The problem is that all my attempts to make the image available for the image provider fail. I have tried using a Q_PROPERTY and a QImage member inside the class, but my provider always returns a null image when I try to access it to return.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question
Problem solved. Here is the solution step by step:

1 - Create a `class` that inherits from `QQuickImageProvider` and `QObject` and inside it create a `Image` member `(QImage)` that is the image to be provided.

```
class provedorImagem : public QObject, public QQuickImageProvider
```

Implement the `virtual requestImage` method. This is the method that will return the image to Qml

```
QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
```

Create a method to load the provider’s image to return

```
void provedorImagem::carregaImagem(QImage imagemRecebida)
{
    imagem = imagemRecebida;
}
```

Now set it as the engine image provider in the `main.cpp` file

```
provedorImagem *provedorImg = new provedorImagem;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ProvedorImagem", provedorImg);
```

2 - Create another `class` that inherits from `QObject`.

```
class processaImagem : public QObject
```

Inside this class you must implement a method that will get the image from `camera` provider, perform the image modifications and return the modified image.
PS: The `p_caminhoImagem` is a `property` that I created inside the `processaImagem class` that receives the `camera preview path`.

```
QImage processaImagem::carregaImagem()
{
    QUrl caminhoImagem(p_caminhoImagem);
    QQmlEngine *engine = QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this)->engine();
    QQmlImageProviderBase *imageProviderBase = engine->imageProvider(caminhoImagem.host());
    QQuickImageProvider *imageProvider = static_cast<QQuickImageProvider*>(imageProviderBase);


    QSize imageSize;
    QString imageId = caminhoImagem.path().remove(0, 1);
    QImage imagem = imageProvider->requestImage(imageId, &imageSize, imageSize);

    if(imagem.isNull())
    {
        imagem = QImage();
    }
    else
    {
        //Perform the modifications
    }

    return imagem;
}
```

3 - Now is the main part. The image `requestImage` provider method  must receive the modified image from the `processaImagem class` to provide it to QML. To do it the provider `class pointer` must be accessible to the QML file, so, in the `main.cpp` file just make the pointer available to QML as a `property`

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ProvedorImagem", provedorImg);
```

and register the `processaImagem class` as a QML type

```
qmlRegisterType<processaImagem>("ProcessaImagemQml", 1, 0, "ProcessaImagem");
```

Now we link it inside the QML file

```
ProvedorImagem.carregaImagem(processaImagem.carregaImagem());
```

4 - It is done. Now just request the image from the provider:

```
imagemPreview.source = "image://provedor/imagemEditada_" + camera.numeroImagem.toString();
```

Here is the entire code:

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <QtQml>

#include "processaimagem.h"
#include "provedorimagem.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<processaImagem>("ProcessaImagemQml", 1, 0, "ProcessaImagem");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    provedorImagem *provedorImg = new provedorImagem;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ProvedorImagem", provedorImg);

    engine.addImageProvider("provedor", provedorImg);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtMultimedia 5.4

import ProcessaImagemQml 1.0

Window {
    visible: true

    width: 360
    height: 640

    maximumHeight: 640
    minimumHeight: 640

    maximumWidth: 360
    minimumWidth: 360

    title: "Camera Preview Test"

    Rectangle {
        id: principal

        anchors.fill: parent

        ProcessaImagem {
            id: processaImagem

            caminhoImagem: camera.caminhoPreview
            caminhoSalvar: camera.caminhoSalvar
            rectRecorte: camera.rectRecorte
            tamanhoImagem: camera.tamanhoImagem
            anguloOrientacaoCamera: camera.orientation
            posicaoCamera: camera.position

            onCaminhoImagemChanged: {
                rectRecorte = cameraView.mapRectToSource(Qt.rect(cameraView.x, cameraView.y, cameraView.width, cameraView.height));
                tamanhoImagem = Qt.size(cameraView.sourceRect.width, cameraView.sourceRect.height);
                ProvedorImagem.carregaImagem(processaImagem.carregaImagem());
            }

            onCaminhoSalvarChanged: {
                removeImagemSalva();
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: cameraRectangle

            width: parent.width
            height: parent.width

            anchors.top: parent.top

            color: "lightGrey"

            visible: true

            Camera {
                id: camera

                property string caminhoPreview: ""
                property string caminhoSalvar: ""
                property int numeroImagem: 0

                captureMode: Camera.CaptureStillImage

                imageCapture {
                    onImageCaptured: {
                        camera.caminhoPreview = preview;

                        camera.stop();

                        imagemPreview.source = "image://provedor/imagemEditada_" + camera.numeroImagem.toString();

                        camera.numeroImagem = camera.numeroImagem + 1;

                        imagemPreviewRectangle.visible = true;

                        cameraRectangle.visible = false;
                    }

                    onImageSaved: {
                        camera.caminhoSalvar = path;
                    }
                }
            }

            VideoOutput {
                id: cameraView

                visible: true

                focus: visible

                anchors.fill: parent

                source: camera
                orientation: camera.orientation
                fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectCrop
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: imagemPreviewRectangle

            width: parent.width
            height: parent.width

            anchors.top: parent.top

            color: "lightGrey"

            visible: false

            Image {
                id: imagemPreview

                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: controleRectangle

            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height - cameraRectangle.height

            color: "grey"

            anchors.top: cameraRectangle.bottom

            Button {
                id: tirarFotoButton

                text: "Tirar foto"

                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.top: parent.top

                onClicked: {
                    camera.imageCapture.capture();
                }
            }

            Button {
                id: novaFotoButton

                text: "Tirar nova foto"

                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.top: parent.top

                onClicked: {
                    camera.start();

                    imagemPreviewRectangle.visible = false;

                    cameraRectangle.visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

processaimagem.h

```
#ifndef PROCESSAIMAGEM_H
#define PROCESSAIMAGEM_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QImage>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickImageProvider>
#include <QFile>

#include "provedorimagem.h"

class processaImagem : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString caminhoImagem READ caminhoImagem WRITE setCaminhoImagem NOTIFY caminhoImagemChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString caminhoSalvar READ caminhoSalvar WRITE setCaminhoSalvar NOTIFY caminhoSalvarChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QRect rectRecorte READ rectRecorte WRITE setRectRecorte NOTIFY rectRecorteChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QSize tamanhoImagem READ tamanhoImagem WRITE setTamanhoImagem NOTIFY tamanhoImagemChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int anguloOrientacaoCamera READ anguloOrientacaoCamera WRITE setAnguloOrientacaoCamera NOTIFY anguloOrientacaoCameraChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int posicaoCamera READ posicaoCamera WRITE setPosicaoCamera NOTIFY posicaoCameraChanged)

public slots:
    QImage carregaImagem();
    void removeImagemSalva();

public:
    processaImagem(QObject *parent = 0);

    QString caminhoImagem() const;
    void setCaminhoImagem(const QString valor);

    QString caminhoSalvar() const;
    void setCaminhoSalvar(const QString valor);

    QRect rectRecorte() const;
    void setRectRecorte(const QRect valor);

    QSize tamanhoImagem() const;
    void setTamanhoImagem(const QSize valor);

    int anguloOrientacaoCamera() const;
    void setAnguloOrientacaoCamera(const int valor);

    int posicaoCamera() const;
    void setPosicaoCamera(const int valor);

private:
    QString p_caminhoImagem = "";
    QString p_caminhoSalvar = "";
    QRect p_rectRecorte = QRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    QSize p_tamanhoImagem = QSize(0, 0);
    int p_anguloOrientacaoCamera = 0;
    int p_posicaoCamera = 0;

signals:
    void caminhoImagemChanged();
    void caminhoSalvarChanged();
    void rectRecorteChanged();
    void tamanhoImagemChanged();
    void anguloOrientacaoCameraChanged();
    void posicaoCameraChanged();
};

#endif // PROCESSAIMAGEM_H
```

processaimagem.cpp

```
#include "processaimagem.h"

#include <QDebug>

processaImagem::processaImagem(QObject *parent)
{

}

QImage processaImagem::carregaImagem()
{
    QUrl caminhoImagem(p_caminhoImagem);
    QQmlEngine *engine = QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this)->engine();
    QQmlImageProviderBase *imageProviderBase = engine->imageProvider(caminhoImagem.host());
    QQuickImageProvider *imageProvider = static_cast<QQuickImageProvider*>(imageProviderBase);


    QSize imageSize;
    QString imageId = caminhoImagem.path().remove(0, 1);
    QImage imagem = imageProvider->requestImage(imageId, &imageSize, imageSize);

    if(imagem.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << "Erro ao carregar a imagem";
        imagem = QImage();
    }
    else
    {
        if((p_anguloOrientacaoCamera == 90) || (p_anguloOrientacaoCamera == 270))
        {
            int larguraImagem = p_tamanhoImagem.width();
            int alturaImagem = p_tamanhoImagem.height();

            p_tamanhoImagem.setWidth(alturaImagem);
            p_tamanhoImagem.setHeight(larguraImagem);

            int recorteX = p_rectRecorte.x();
            int recorteY = p_rectRecorte.y();
            int recorteLargura = p_rectRecorte.width();
            int recorteAltura = p_rectRecorte.height();

            p_rectRecorte.setRect(recorteY, recorteX, recorteAltura, recorteLargura);

            if(imagem.size().width() > imagem.size().height())
            {
                QTransform rotacao;
                rotacao.rotate(360 - p_anguloOrientacaoCamera);
                imagem = imagem.transformed(rotacao);

                qDebug() << "Rodou";
            }
        }

        if(imagem.width() != p_tamanhoImagem.width())
        {
            imagem = imagem.scaled(p_tamanhoImagem);
        }

        imagem = imagem.copy(p_rectRecorte);
    }

    return imagem;
}

void processaImagem::removeImagemSalva()
{
    QFile::remove(p_caminhoSalvar);
}

QString processaImagem::caminhoImagem() const
{
    return p_caminhoImagem;
}

void processaImagem::setCaminhoImagem(const QString valor)
{
    if (valor != p_caminhoImagem)
    {
        p_caminhoImagem = valor;
        emit caminhoImagemChanged();
    }
}

QString processaImagem::caminhoSalvar() const
{
    return p_caminhoSalvar;
}

void processaImagem::setCaminhoSalvar(const QString valor)
{
    if (valor != p_caminhoSalvar)
    {
        p_caminhoSalvar = valor;
        emit caminhoSalvarChanged();
    }
}

QRect processaImagem::rectRecorte() const
{
    return p_rectRecorte;
}

void processaImagem::setRectRecorte(const QRect valor)
{
    bool alterou = false;

    if (valor.x() != p_rectRecorte.x())
    {
        p_rectRecorte.setX(valor.x());
        alterou = true;
    }

    if (valor.y() != p_rectRecorte.y())
    {
        p_rectRecorte.setY(valor.y());
        alterou = true;
    }

    if (valor.width() != p_rectRecorte.width())
    {
        p_rectRecorte.setWidth(valor.width());
        alterou = true;
    }

    if (valor.height() != p_rectRecorte.height())
    {
        p_rectRecorte.setHeight(valor.height());
        alterou = true;
    }

    if(alterou)
    {
        emit rectRecorteChanged();
    }
}

QSize processaImagem::tamanhoImagem() const
{
    return p_tamanhoImagem;
}

void processaImagem::setTamanhoImagem(const QSize valor)
{
    bool alterou = false;

    if (valor.width() != p_tamanhoImagem.width())
    {
        p_tamanhoImagem.setWidth(valor.width());
        alterou = true;
    }

    if (valor.height() != p_tamanhoImagem.height())
    {
        p_tamanhoImagem.setHeight(valor.height());
        alterou = true;
    }

    if(alterou)
    {
        emit tamanhoImagemChanged();
    }
}

int processaImagem::anguloOrientacaoCamera() const
{
    return p_anguloOrientacaoCamera;
}

void processaImagem::setAnguloOrientacaoCamera(const int valor)
{
    if (valor != p_anguloOrientacaoCamera)
    {
        p_anguloOrientacaoCamera = valor;
        emit anguloOrientacaoCameraChanged();
    }
}

int processaImagem::posicaoCamera() const
{
    return p_posicaoCamera;
}

void processaImagem::setPosicaoCamera(const int valor)
{
    if (valor != p_posicaoCamera)
    {
        p_posicaoCamera = valor;
        emit posicaoCameraChanged();
    }
}
```

provedorimagem.h

```
#ifndef PROVEDORIMAGEM_H
#define PROVEDORIMAGEM_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QImage>
#include <QQuickImageProvider>

class provedorImagem : public QObject, public QQuickImageProvider
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    provedorImagem();

    QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize);

public slots:
    void carregaImagem(QImage imagemRecebida);

private:
    QImage imagem;
};

#endif // PROVEDORIMAGEM_H
```

provedorimagem.cpp

```
#include "provedorimagem.h"

#include <QDebug>

provedorImagem::provedorImagem() : QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Image)
{

}

QImage provedorImagem::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
{
    if(imagem.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << "Erro ao prover a imagem";
    }

    return imagem;
}

void provedorImagem::carregaImagem(QImage imagemRecebida)
{
    imagem = imagemRecebida;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. The example would, however, benefit from being written with English class and member names. Not everyone in the world reads Portugese...

Comment: I didn't write it in English because it is part of an app of mine and this app is written in Portuguese.

Comment: @KlaasvanGend I didn't understand where is this variable coming from: `imagemEditada_`. GuiDupas please help.

Comment: It comes from the `provedorImagem` that uses the `processaImagem` to get and modify the image taken.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this is via `QQuickImageProvider` because it performs and has the most options for customization. However, it is not usually the first choice, because it's non-trivial code.

If you are looking for a shortcut solution, you can convert the QImage to a data-URI QUrl. Once it's a data-URI QUrl it can be given to QML.

```cpp
QUrl imageToUrl(const QImage& image)
{
    QByteArray byteArray;
    QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    int quality = -1; // (default) compressed data, slower
    // int quality = 100; // large uncompressed data, faster
    image.save(&buffer, "png", quality);
    QString base64 = QString::fromUtf8(byteArray.toBase64());
    return QString("data:image/png;base64,") + base64;
}
```

Whilst the code is short to implement, its use case is limited to low-frequency applications. If you attempt to update a QML image with data-URI arriving at a high frequency, QML may show an image that's constantly flickering or, even, an image that never renders before the next data-URI arrives. If you're suffering from such a scenario you can consider setting `quality = 100` to increase the speed at which the data-URI is generated and, subsequently, rendered.