# How to draw a QR code with QML in native C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to generate the Qr code in **QML in QT creator v5.7** so can you please help me to which qr library i will use and how to implement qr code.

Comment: The other question is about doing that with QWidgets, this one is about doing it in QML.

Comment: Ok, so the question boils down to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422265/pass-qimage-to-qml

Answer (score 4):

A solution would be to use the QZXing library: https://github.com/ftylitak/qzxing#howToEncodingQtQuick

The sample usage is quite simple:
Include the library in your project and then in you QML code you can do :

```
import QZXing 2.3

Image{
    source: "image://QZXing/encode/" + textToBeEncoded
}
```

If you want to understand how it works under the hood, 
this library is a wrapper around the famous [zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) library and it exposes a [`QQuickImageProvider`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html) that can be invoked from QML with the image url : `image://QZXing/...`.

This image provider takes the text to be encoded and pass it to a c++ function generating a `QImage` from the data and returns this `QImage` to the qml engine that will display it.

Comment: This is to decode the QR by providing image to QR.

Comment: @MohammadKanan no

Comment: ah ok, I missed the second paragraph

Comment: Check this https://github.com/ftylitak/qzxing#how-to-include and if you have further problems open an issue on the github project.

Comment: @TM9412, there few examples in the repository ready for use, did you try one of them