# How to display Image receive from TCPsokcet and display in QML

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt5.12

I want to implement the complete pipeline as :

**opencv (clientapp on Linux platform)** ---socket---> **QT(server opencv on QT platform)**
transfer the image using opencv c++ function through socket  and display image in QMl.

I have called the opencv c++ function from qml using  Q_INVOKABLE but how to send the QImage from c++ function to QML file for display.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt/QML : Send QImage From C++ to QML and Display The QImage On GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691414/qt-qml-send-qimage-from-c-to-qml-and-display-the-qimage-on-gui)

Comment: could you please send me any simple example on these with code

Comment: That answer explained completely, try to implement it and  ask about you exact problem. An example need so many part to attach.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to feed your QML with images, you can use  [QQuickImageProvider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html) class as it says

> The QQuickImageProvider class provides an interface for supporting
> pixmaps and threaded image requests in QML

Comment: its better if any one send me simple code